# How can a Pandas DatetimeArray be sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which contains a `date` column.

I need to get the unique values of that column and then sort them out. I started with:

```
unique_dates = data['date'].unique()
```

Which works well. Next, I need to sort this unique list of dates.

However, I am having issues because `unique_values` is now of `DatetimeArray` type, and this does not have the `sort()` or `sort_values()` methods I can find in a DataFrame.

If I could convert it to just a NumPy array, I could sort it, but I am not finding a way to do that either...

How can I get a `DatetimeArray` sorted? Is there another way of doing this that I am not considering?

Thanks!

Eduardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DatetimeArray` is a [flavour of ExtensionArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.DatetimeArray.html).

ExtensionArrays don't have a `sort` or `sort_values` method, but [they do have `argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html), so we can achieve sorting using:

```
unique_dates_sorted = unique_dates[unique_dates.argsort()]
```

i.e. we get the indexes which result in the sorted array, then use those to produce a reordered array.

A complete mini-example:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dates = [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)] * 50 + [datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)] * 50 + [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)] * 50
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['date'])
unique_dates = df['date'].unique()
unique_dates_sorted = unique_dates[unique_dates.argsort()]
print(unique_dates_sorted)
```

giving:

```
[datetime.date(2020, 1, 1) datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want first converting the `DatetimeArray` to a `list` and then sorting it using `sorted`.

```
unique_dates_sorted = sorted(list(unique_dates)))
```